# Writing find method recursively, LinkedList

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I need to write find method recursively, and when I'm trying to find x and I found it 
I need to move x to the head of the linked list

for example if the list was 
head --> 15 --> 20 --> 5 --> 10

and I run find(5), then the list will be
head --> 5 --> 15 --> 20 --> 10

```
private boolean find (int x)
{
    Node pointer = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(pointer != null)
    {
        if( pointer.data != x)
        {
            pointer = pointer.next;
            find(x);      
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with what you posted?

Comment: how do I set x to be the head after i find it

Comment: im also getting sttackOverflowError when I run it because of find(x) inside if statement

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write a recursive helper method such as this:

```
private boolean find(int x, Node node) {
    if (node == null)
        return false;
    return node.data == x || find(x, node.next);
}
```

Then the standard `find` would simply be

```
private boolean find(int x) {
    return find(x, head);  // start search from head
}
```

The adding/removing component should not be hard to implement with this approach in mind: you can remove the appropriate node in the first `find` method if it is found and add the node to the front of the list in the second `find` as a new node containing `x` (assuming `find(x, head)` returns true).

Comment: @Downvoter Could you leave a comment?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, im also wondering how can I move the found x to the head

Comment: **+1** I typically always choose an approach like this, passing the `Node` in to the recursive method makes things much simpler.

Comment: Your post simply doesn't answer the question as asked: "how do I set x to be the head after i find it". It just says "should not be hard to implement".

Comment: @melpomene Alright fair enough - I expanded on that.

Answer (score 0):

Private boolean find(int x)
{
 Node retval = recursiveFind(x, head, parent)
 If retVal != null
RetVal.next = head
 Return true
}

Private Node recursiveFind(Int x, node head, node parent)
{
If head == null && parent == null
Return null;

If head.value == x
Parent.next = head.next:
Return head

Else return recursiveFind(x, head.next, head)

Im on a smatphone but something like that

Some

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've had to play with java and linked lists (and written off the top of my head without testing), so this may not work copied/pasted, but try something like this:

```
Node linkedListHead = ...;

public void find(int target){
    Node foundNode = findRec(target, linkedListHead, null);

    if(foundNode != null){
        // assumes Node takes in the Data first, then a Node
        linkedListHead = new Node(target, linkedListHead);
        foundNode.next = foundNode.next.next;
    }
}

private void findRec(int target, Node currentNode, Node previousNode){

    if(currentNode == null){
        return null;

    } else if(currentNode.data == target){
        return previousNode;

    } else {
        return find(target, currentNode.next, currentNode);
    }
}
```

The point is to keep a reference to the previous node during the findRec() method and return that so the next node after (that contains the search target) and be removed from the list.